# Android Studio and Kotlin code inspection is unusable when there are multiple errors in file

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, code-inspection

In Kotlin files when I have multiple errors, Android Studio becomes unusable.
When I make any change everything freezes for a few seconds, when I disable code inspection then it works normally.

This does not happen with java

Is this an issue with my pc or Kotlin or android studio, and is there any kind of a solution

Comment: What are your PC specifications ?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be an issue with Kotlin.
Ensure that both the Kotlin plugin and Android Studio plugins are up to date.
The IDE can hang if it does not have enough memory allocated.
To change the memory allocation, go to **Edit -> Edit Custom VM option** and update the memory allocation as shown in the image below. This might help.

[image: Visual of Menu Item]

If you need additional assistance finding this setting, please refer to the [official Android Studio Configuration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config).

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your kotlin version?

I passed over a similar problem because of updating some implements or kotlin,google-services version etc. in the middle of a project!

After i returned the previous version; it is fixed...

**So** try using previous version for example `kotlin_version = '1.3.40'` in the project's build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.40'
    ...
    ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    ...
```